# React Router not loading component on route

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to navigate to a link `/login`, when I click the actual link I can see the url change in the browser but the `Login` component isn't loaded:

```
// App.tsx

import React from 'react';
import {BrowserRouter as Router, Route} from 'react-router-dom';

import Header from './components/Header/Header';
import Login from './components/Login/Login';

const App = () => {
  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <Header />
      <Router>
        <Route path="/login" exact component={Login} />
      </Router>
    </React.Fragment>
  );
};

export default App;
```

```
// Header.tsx

import React from 'react';
import {BrowserRouter, Link} from 'react-router-dom';

const Header = () => {
  return (
    <BrowserRouter>
      <Link to="/login">login</Link>
    </BrowserRouter>
  );
};

export default Header;
```

And the actual login component:

```
// Login.tsx

import React from 'react';
// import {useHistory} from 'react-router-dom';

const Login = () => {
  console.log('login component opened');
  return (
    <div>
      Login
    </div>
  );
};

export default Login;
```

When I click the link in the `header` component I get navigated to `http://localhost:8080/login` but the component isn't loading. Also if I refresh that page `http://localhost:8080/login` I get a message:

> Cannot GET /login

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**First, the `Link` component needs to be inside `BrowserRouter`**

```
const App = () => {
  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <Router>
        <Header />
        <Route path="/login" exact component={Login} />
      </Router>
    </React.Fragment>
  );
};
```

**Also, you don't need to wrap `BrowserRouter` around `Link` component:**

```
import React from 'react';
import {BrowserRouter, Link} from 'react-router-dom';

const Header = () => {
  return (
      <Link to="/login">login</Link>
  );
};

export default Header;
```

Comment: Thanks, than I misunderstood the error. `Uncaught Error: Invariant failed: You should not use <Link> outside a <Router>` thought I had to put the `link` inside the component in a router, but it's the component that has to be in the router.

Comment: Yeah, I found your issue from that error too.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
const Header = () => {
  return (
    <BrowserRouter>
      <Link to="/login">login</Link>
      <Switch>
          <Route exact path="/login">
              <Login />
          </Route>
      </Switch>
    </BrowserRouter>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Inside App.tsx your import shouldn't look like this:

```
import Login from './components/Login/login';
```

It should be like this instead:

```
import Login from './components/Login/Login';
```

You used a wrong file name for the Login component. The first letter must be uppercase.

Comment: That was a mistake in formatting the question, but not what was causing the error